# Can Recursive implementation, also known as the “recursive backtracker” algorithm be used in Python3?

Tags: python, maze

I am trying to make a maze generator, and does Recursive implementation, also known as the “recursive backtracker” algorithm be used in Python3?

Comment: Python is one of many turing complete languages. By definition, any algorithm that can be implemented can be implemented in python.

Answer (score 1):

> Can Recursive implementation, also known as the “recursive backtracker” algorithm be used in Python3?

Yes.